# mover el final del rectangulo

Tags: css

la base del rectangulo no deberia moverse o al menos que no se note mucho, solo quiero que se mueva el final del rectangulo. **quiero simular un brazo robotico**

Nota: **El final es el lado izquierdo**

```css
body{
padding:100px;
}

.div{
    animation: put-put 2s infinite;
    position:relative;}

.div:after{
    content:"";
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    left:0px;
    top:-35px;
    position:absolute;
    border-top:7px solid #444;

    transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes put-put {
    0% {  transform: rotate(30deg); }
    5% { transform: rotate(20deg); }
    20% { transform: rotate(10deg); }
    35% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    40% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    60% { transform: rotate(10deg); }
    75% { transform: rotate(20deg); }
    80% {  transform: rotate(25deg);}
    100% { transform: rotate(30deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
```

Comment: A que te refieres con "el final del rectángulo" ?

Comment: @CamiloVasquez al lado izquierdo lo pondre en la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La propiedad `animation` se la debes dar al `:after` de tu `<div>`, además para que quede mas fluida la animación he reducido los tiempos:

```css
body{
padding:100px;
}

.div{
    position:relative;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.div:after{
    content:"";
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    left:0px;
    top:-35px;
    position:absolute;
    border-top:7px solid #444;
    animation: put-put 2s infinite;
    transform: rotate(30deg) scaleX(-1);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    filter: FlipV;
}

@-webkit-keyframes put-put {
    0% {  transform: rotate(30deg); }
    50% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(30deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
```

Comment: el otro extremo deberia moverse

Comment: @hubman osea que es al revés la animación?

Comment: si es alreves podrias modificarlo

Comment: @hubman listo ya te he modificado la respuesta !